# ¿Como recibir todas los datos por $_POST, sin ser asignada por una variable?

Tags: php, formularios, variables

Tengo el siguiente ciclo que me convierte los datos resibidos por `POST` de una vez sin asignarla a una variable Ejm:

```
////Envio $_POST['name']='valentina'
```

y con

```
if(@$_POST)
{
    foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor)
    {

        $asig = "$" . $campo . "='" . htmlspecialchars($valor,ENT_QUOTES) . "';";
        eval($asig);

    }
    echo $name  // $name = valentina
}
```

Pero por cuestiones de seguridad quiero quitar la función `eval()` ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar la función `eval()`? o que otro metodo puedo utilizar para reemplazar el `foreach`?

Comment: Para que utilizas la funcion `eval()`?? @FerchoJerez

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso puedes evitar el uso de `eval` (que comporta riesgos de seguridad) con [variables variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Prueba con:

```
$$campo = htmlspecialchars($valor, ENT_QUOTES);
```